# Question closed as dup but link to duplicate is a dead link

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

In such a case should the question be reopened? I am especially referring to [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/252357/how-can-i-access-blocked-sites-while-in-china). You'll find that the question that's supposedly a duplication refers to a 404 page not found -- a dead link.

A quick search on superuser does not reveal any other obvious duplicates. Should this question be reopened in such a case since the reason for closing it is no longer valid?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Random deleted that; I think it's a valid question, though perhaps the duplicate has a better *rationale* and *reason* for asking.

Comment: It was closed as off topic by some other moderator. Those are on the chopping block after some time.

Comment: It's a valid question but it already doesn't load for me here in China (along with this one: http://superuser.com/questions/48361/help-me-get-past-chinas-great-firewall-and-reach-blocked-sites) -- hopefully it doesn't get superuser.com fully blocked. :(